# How to add Custom summaries for autogenerated colums?

Tags: jquery, ignite-ui, iggrid

I am using iggrid and my autoGenerateColumns: true, is true. There are no fixed no of columns generated every time.

I want to use custom summary to calculate sum of each rows of a dynamic column and show it at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe as a custom summary is a summary that shows the sum of all rows, which is supported out-of-the-box by the igGrid (if Summaries have been enabled) and could be setup by setting the [column settings](https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2018.2/ui.iggridsummaries#options:columnSettings) and the [summary operand type to “sum”](https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2018.2/ui.iggridsummaries#options:columnSettings.summaryOperands.type) in the “Summary” options.

Enabling the “Summaries” feature would work out-of-the-box if your columns contain numeric values.

If you want to show a specific summary (in your case the “sum”), but you don’t know the column keys, there is a way to hide the rest of the default summaries by using a CSS selector, like this one:

```
<style>
    tfoot[role='rowgroup'] tr:not([id$='_sum']) {
        display: none
    }
</style
```

If the “Summaries” feature has been enabled, the above CSS would hide all summary rows except the “Sum”, which I believe is what you want to do.
Keep in mind this would hide the rest of the summary operands, effectively leaving only a single row with the sum summary, but it would show summaries for all numeric columns.
If you want to show a “sum” summary for specific columns only, try getting the columns of the grid after it has been initialized, by using something like this:

```
$("#grid").igGrid("option", "columns")
```

This would allow you to set the column settings for the Summary feature even after it has been initialized. In case you have a column with the key of “UnitPrice” and you want to disable its summary after the grid has been initialized, the code would look like this:

```
$("#grid").igGridSummaries("option", "columnSettings", [{ columnKey: "UnitPrice", allowSummaries: false  }]);
```

I think transforming the API data before databinding the igGrid so that the dates are being displayed vertically on different rows, instead of visualizing then as columns, might be a better idea – this would allow you to use the Summaries more easily and sum the number of days a student has been absent.

Please note that in order to use the Summaries feature it should be enabled in your grid features configuration, for example:

```
features: [
    {
        name: 'Summaries'
    }
]
```